# SMOTE sampling in caret package in R

Tags: r, sampling, caret

when using caret packge in the trainControl you can use "smote" sampling.
what is the default parameters the train in caret are using for smote??

parameters such as: 
perc.over = 300, k = 8, perc.under = 100..

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                     number = 10,
                     repeats = 10, 
                     search = "grid", 
                     returnData = TRUE,
                     returnResamp = "final",
                     savePredictions = "all",
                     classProbs = TRUE,
                     sampling = "smote",
                     summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
                     selectionFunction = "best",
                     allowParallel = TRUE)
```

Comment: Opening again this question after a while... Overall, is it advisable to use caret default sampling methods? I feel the control over the rebalanced data set is a bit lost. Is it a better option to just build the dataset by themselves using a package like imbalance?

Answer (score 2):

I reproduced the example of https://topepo.github.io/caret/subsampling-for-class-imbalances.html and tried another one. Results are:

*perc.over* = 200

*perc.under* = 200

It seems that the parameters are those of *usage* of the function *SMOTE* in the *DMwR* documentation (pag. 82):

> **Usage**
>
> SMOTE(form, data, perc.over = 200, k = 5, perc.under = 200,
>   learner = NULL, ...)

In *usage* *k = 5*, but I verified only *perc.over* and *perc.under*:

```
library(caret)
library(DMwR)

set.seed(2969)
imbal_train <- twoClassSim(10000, intercept = -20, linearVars = 20)
table(imbal_train\$Class)

set.seed(9560)
smote_train <- SMOTE(Class ~ ., data  = imbal_train)                         
table(smote_train\$Class)[2]

perc.over <- 100*(table(smote_train\$Class)[2]-table(imbal_train\$Class)[2])/table(imbal_train\$Class)[2]
perc.under <- 100*table(smote_train\$Class)[1]/(table(smote_train\$Class)[2]-table(imbal_train\$Class)[2])
```

perc.over = 200

perc.under = 200

```
set.seed(1234)
imbal_train <- twoClassSim(10000, intercept = -40, linearVars = 40)
table(imbal_train\$Class)

set.seed(5678)
smote_train <- SMOTE(Class ~ ., data  = imbal_train)                         
table(smote_train\$Class)

perc.over <- 100*(table(smote_train\$Class)[2]-table(imbal_train\$Class)[2])/table(imbal_train$Class)[2]
perc.under <- 100*table(smote_train\$Class)[1]/(table(smote_train\$Class)[2]-table(imbal_train\$Class)[2])
```

perc.over = 200

perc.under = 200